# How to access locked hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, security, partitioning

I have a hard drive with an old 12.04 server install and a data partition on it. I have the hard drive hooked up to my current desktop using a usb to sata adapter with external power supply. I am on my 12.04 ubuntu OS install on my desktop. I am able to open the server install partition but whenever I try to access the data partition it says: This location could not be displayed, You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1". Is there a solution to this besides re-formatting?

Still having trouble so if anyone could be more specific that would be nice.

The output of `lsblk` is:

```
user1@user1-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RG279UA-ABA:~$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0  74.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0  19.5G  0 part  
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda3                  8:3    0   9.8G  0 part  
├─sda5                  8:5    0   9.8G  0 part  /media/5058-F505
├─sda6                  8:6    0     2G  0 part  
├─sda7                  8:7    0    14G  0 part  
├─sda8                  8:8    0     2G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap1 (dm-0) 252:0    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda9                  8:9    0  15.9G  0 part  /
sdb                     8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                  8:17   0  18.6G  0 part  /media/71d5ea0b-d815-4756-ba29-2391b13f8285
├─sdb2                  8:18   0     1K  0 part  
├─sdb5                  8:21   0 121.1G  0 part  /media/c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1
└─sdb6                  8:22   0   2.8G  0 part  
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

sdb5 is the partition I'm trying to access. I named it `/mnt/owncloudData` when setting it up on the server.

output of `ls -la /media`:

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root     4096 Sep 13 04:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root     4096 Aug  5 12:56 ..
drwx------  7 user1 user1    8192 Dec 31  1969 5058-F505
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root     4096 Sep  2 02:01 71d5ea0b-d815-4756-ba29-2391b13f8285
drwxrwx---  4 root  www-data 4096 Nov 13  2013 c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1
```

Comment: [1] do you have adm. permissions? [2] if you run in a terminal `lsblk`, could you make an educated guess what the actual partition is?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, yes I know which one it is, I tried `sudo chown root` using the partition name /dev/... and the mount point /media/cam/.... but still could not get access

Comment: could you paste the output of lsblk in your question and indicate which partition it is?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, just updated the question.

Comment: One more question: could you run `ls -la /media` and see what it sais about `c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1`?

Comment: could you run `sudo chown -R username:username /media/c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1`, where username is your_username?

Comment: I believed that worked, now how can I make it appear under devices in the file manager?

Comment: You can browse to /media/c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1 in nautilus if I am correct?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I can navigate to it from terminal but how can I make it appear in the file manager under devices?

Comment: If you unplug it and plug it in again (usb) doesn't it appear? I think I would save the data and reformat, give it an appropriate label etc if you do not need it in a server anymore.

Comment: I was afraid of doing that for fear of losing access so I didn't unplug it, but it just popped up by itself a few secs ago, not sure why it took so long but oh well, thank you very much.

Comment: Great! would you mind if I made a story of it? (answer)

Comment: By all means yes, I was hoping you would.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17123/discussion-between-skateguy-and-jacob-vlijm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output of `lsblk`, it turns out the partition is already mounted, in `/media/c436695a-0830-4e33-b6c6-61a54d801ab1`. The output of `ls -la /media` made clear why you did not have access to the partition; owner (`root`) and `group` (`www-data`) have full permissions (`rwx`) , others (like you) have no permission at all (`---`), that includes read access.

What you can do is change the owner of the partition with the command: `sudo chown -R user:user /partition` (where `user` is `your_username`), and optionally change the permissions of the partition, at least to save your data. After that I would reformat the disk, repartition, give it an appropriate label etc, if you do not use it in your server anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have permission to use sudo on your desktop, then you have enough permissions to view anything connected to it.

You also, of course, have authority to change the permissions on the disk, if you so desire.  It depends on what you want to do.  If you simply want to access the data, but not use the drive any more, you can mount the drive, then use `sudo chown` to make yourself the owner, and that will probably fix everything.

This is all basic linux.

Comment: How do I mount the drive from terminal?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like it may be getting mounted automatically by the OS, but you simply can't access it - is this correct?  If so, it probably gets mounted to /media, so you can try changing the owner of the files and directories.  You won't be able to change the directory where it's mounted, though.

Comment: To answer your question, though, you use the mount command... something like `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`; you would substitute the partition you actually want to mount for sdb1 (you can find it by typing `sudo blkid` to get a list of devices.