# Access denied on hard drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I just formatted a hard drive in my computer and created an ext4 partition using KDE Partition Manager.
Then I mounted it to /media/hassan also using KDE Partition Manager

I can see the drive in the file browser but I cannot create files on it or copy files to it.

However, I managed to create a folder using the `sudo mkdir /media/hassan/Hassan/newfolder` command.
Also I tried to change the permissions of the drive using `sudo chmod ug+w /media/hassan/Hassan`.
(hassan is my user name, Hassan is the name of the drive)

Still I cannot create files or copy files to the hard drive.
Am I missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to `chown` it, not `chmod`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem.
Do some programs (e.g. cloud clients) need other permissions than user access (the current permissions of the drive are ```hannes users```)
Or should this permission work for most applications?

Comment: It should work for anything that runs under your user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access locked hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518833/how-to-access-locked-hard-drive)

Comment: Yes definitely, thank you!